# Showing that a subspace is indeed a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The question is as in the title. Prove that every subspace $U$ of a vector space $V$ is a vector space with the same operations as in $V$. The main issue I'm having here is with that last part, *"with the same operations as in $V$."*

We're given that a subset is a subspace if $\alpha u + \beta v\in U$ for all $\alpha,\beta\in F$ and all $u,v\in U$.

I'll note that first (Given the axioms the book states for a vector space) this isn't actually true. The book requires a vector space to include a zero element, and the empty set is trivially a subspace, but it's not a vector space under the book's definition. Putting that aside, and assuming that $U$ is non-empty, I'll continue.

I understand that I need to prove that all the axioms we want to hold for a vector space holds for the subspace. Take e.g. associativity of vector addition, i.e. $u + (v+w) = (u+v) +w$. I don't know that this addition is the same as in the parent space $V$, right? Worse still for e.g. the requirement that $1u = u$ for all $u\in U$. The condition for being a subspace doesn't involve multiplication at all, and furthermore I don't know that the multiplication defined for the field is the same as for the vector space over that field. The rule regarding $\alpha u$ (for some $u$ in $V$) might be completely different from the one for $\alpha\beta$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in F$. This is in fact trivially true since one maps to $V$ and the other to $F$.

So, how could I ever prove that $1u = u$ for $u\in U$ when the *multiplication itself is unknown*?

Comment: All operations in your subspace are the operations from the ambient space, by definition, they are just applied to some vectors, not all of them. But if some identity holds in the space it will continue to hold when the vectors are taken from a subset of it. The only concern is that all expressions involved belong to the subspace, but that is guaranteed by the closure properties. For example, the closure implies that $\alpha u\in U$ when $u\in U$ for *any* $\alpha$, not just $\alpha=1$. One exception is the zero vector axiom, but $0\in U$ because $0=0u$ for any $u\in U$.

Comment: So is the question just stated vaguely? In the back of my mind I thought that perhaps that "with" in "with the same operations" might be supposed to be read as a "given the same operations".

Comment: I wouldn't call it vague, how else would one interpret "the same operations"? In any case, this is a standard way to state it.

Comment: I interpreted it as "Prove that every subspace is a vector space. Prove that this vector space has the same operations as the parent space." I.e. that having the same operations is a consequence of the definition above, rather than part of the definition.

Comment: It is not a "vector space" until it is equipped with some operations, which is why it says "with the same operations". Having any operations, the same or not, can not be a consequence until they are defined, just specifying a subset on which they are to be defined does not do that.

Comment: To get an answer to this you will have to say how your book defines "subspace". (What you are stating as a theorem seems to me to be the only sensible definition of "subspace".) As to your point about $0$: this is a $0$-ary operator on $V$ so if $U$ has the same operators it will contain the zero element.